# Apache Spark Configuration

Tags: apache-spark, configuration

I'm facing memory issue while running spark configuration and i have changed the settings to max memory but it's still not working. Please check out the following issue:
Command-

```
spark2-shell --conf "spark.default.parallelism=40" --executor.memory 8g --driver-memory 32g --conf "spark.ui.port=4404" --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2048m --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=200s
```

> Error- ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 9 on
>   ampanacdddbp01.au.amp.local: Executor heartbeat timed out after 123643
>   ms WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 19.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 19,
>   ampanacdddbp01.au.amp.local, executor 9): ExecutorLostFailure
>   (executor 9  e running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out
>   after 123643 ms WARN spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 3 with
>   no recent heartbeats: 126935 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms ERROR
>   cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 3 on ampanacdddbp01.au.amp.local:
>   Executor heartbeat timed out after 126935 ms ERROR
>   scheduler.TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 23 tasks
>   (1040.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
>   ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Total size of serialized results of 24
>   tasks (1085.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0
>   MB)

Please help me with the configuration and how to fix this "lost executor error".

Answer (score 0):

Default value of parameter "spark.driver.maxResultSize" is 1g which is 1024MB. Since your application is trying to use more that the allocated memory to this property you are getting this error.

Try changing the value as follows :

1. Either pass command line argument while launching spark-shell as "--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g"
2. Set the value of this property at system level in "conf/spark-env.sh"
3. Set the property at sparkContext Level as follows
   conf = SparkConf().set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '4g')
   sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

Hope it Helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Comment: Hey Thanks neeraj. i missed that. But still facing lost executor issue:  ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on ampanacdwdbp01.au.amp.local: Executor heartbeat timed out after 131047 ms
 WARN spark.HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 5 with no recent heartbeats: 123861 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 5 on ampanacdwdbp01.au.amp.local: Executor heartbeat timed out after 123861 ms